# Access parent class methods from within child class constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3. In my form request which extends the request class I am trying to access method from the parent class but it is throwing an error and I can't seem to see why. My form request constructor looks like the following. Am I missing something here?

The call works when I put it in other methods, just not from the constructor where it ideally needs to be.

Accessing the parent below triggers "Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php:601"

```
    protected $test= [];

    public function __construct(myRepositoryInterface $myRepository) {

        $this->myRepository= $myRepository;
        if( parent::has('someName') ){
           $this->test= $myRepository->someMethod(parent::input('someName'));
       }
   }
```

Comment: Create a init() method in the class and call it from the constructor.

Comment: The problem is either in `parent::has` or `parent::input`, or both! Based on the error, I'm willing to bet that somewhere in the parent object, something that is usually defined is not being defined, and that laravel is attempting to call something using that value. It doesn't really have much to do with the `parent::` calls itself, as I first suspected :)

Comment: @Amleonard Yeah I agree, my thoughts on it were that until the constructor had completed its work, I can't access those methods properly. I can call the exact same code in another method and it works, but in the constructor it fails. Thanks.

Comment: @jiraiya I see I see. By all means I'm sure it's accessing both of those properties properly, or else the error you'd be getting would be from that particular script, not from the internals of laravel. To me that means a dependency in the parent class must not be "in place" until after the constructor finishes. Hard for me to tell though :). How did Gala's suggestion work out?

Comment: @Amleonard Yeah I tried Gala's solution but it's the same result with the same error. I thought the answer below might have nailed it but the values return empty. Must be a framework thing as you suggested. It seems the constructor must finish before you have access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems.

First, Laravel's Form Request class is a subclass of Symfony's Request class. If you take a look at that class, it has this constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $query = array(), array $request = array(), array $attributes = array(), array $cookies = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $content = null)
{
    $this->initialize($query, $request, $attributes, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
}
```

You created your own constructor and changed the behavior of the Request class, essentially breaking it. You aren't accepting any of the parameters that the superclass requires.

The `Call to a member function get() on null` gives us a clue. This is the function where `get()` is being called:

```
protected function retrieveItem($source, $key, $default)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $this->$source->all();
    }

    return $this->$source->get($key, $default);
}
```

Your `$source` is null. The `$source` can be something like the `headers` property, which is null because of your new constructor. The error has nothing to do with the parent class' `has` method and everything to do with the constructor.

Second, rather than calling `parent::has()`, you should be calling `$this->has()`.

Finally, I would take that out of the constructor. Initialize your repository somewhere else. If you do need this to be in your constructor for some reason, try accepting all other parameters and then your repository. Remember to call `parent::__construct(...parameters...`) and run your own logic.

Comment: Thanks so much Thomas, this really helped me a lot. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: I had tried using $this->has() also and parent to see what was the issue also in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot call parent::__construct() in the child constructor?

Comment: No sorry I spoke too soon. It stops the error but the methods only return empty values, it seems the content is inaccessible until the constructor has finished its work.